# How to declare a global list object

Tags: vb.net, list

I would like to declare a list above Sub procedure and to be able to add/modify it .

I would like to have something like this:

```
Public lisst As List(Of Decimal)
Private Sub angajati_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
         lisst.Add(1)
         lisst.Add(2)
End Sub
```

When i run the above example i get an error like:

```
 Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

How could i solve the problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not initialized the list (notice the [`New`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/77s47661.aspx)):

```
Public lisst As New List(Of Decimal)
Private Sub angajati_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
         lisst.Add(1)
         lisst.Add(2)
End Sub
```